# do not display output when shordcode is empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a if statement to the code bellow. I'm using shortcodes and I need to achive following ting:
when shortcode number or icon is empty do not display the output e.g value.
now it creates duplicates

Thank you in advance.

```
// service shortcode

add_shortcode('service','service_shortcode');

function service_shortcode($atts,$content = null)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'number' => '','icon' => '', 'title' => ''),$atts));

    $output = '';
    $output .= '<div class="service-box col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">';
    $output .= '<div class="service-box-1 pull-left">';
    $output .= '<span><i class="fa fa-'.$icon.' icon-custom-style"></i></span>';
    $output .= '<span><p class="icon-custom-style">'.$number.'</p></span>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="service-box-2">';
    $output .= '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
    $output .= '<p>'.$content.'</p>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}

// feature shortcode

add_shortcode('feature','feature_shortcode');

function feature_shortcode($atts,$content = null)

if

{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'number' => '','icon' => '', 'title' => '', 'color' => '1'),$atts));

    $output = '';
    $output .= '<div class="feature-box col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">';
    $output .= '<div class="feature-box-1 pull-left color-'.$color.'">';
    $output .= '<span><i class="fa fa-'.$icon.' icon-custom-style"></i></span>';
    $output .= '<span><p class="icon-custom-style">'.$number.'</p></span>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="feature-box-2">';
    $output .= '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
    $output .= '<p>'.$content.'</p>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}

// feature shortcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check to see if the `$shortcode_tags` global variable is empty?

```
global $shortcode_tags;
if (!empty($shortcode_tags)) {
    // shortcode tags not empty; display output
}
```

EDIT:
How about:

```
if (!empty($icon) || !empty($number)) {
    $output = '';
    $output .= '<div class="service-box col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">';
    $output .= '<div class="service-box-1 pull-left">';
    if (!empty($icon)) {
        $output .= '<span><i class="fa fa-'.$icon.' icon-custom-style"></i></span>';
    }
    else {
        $output .= '<span><p class="icon-custom-style">'.$number.'</p></span>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="service-box-2">';
    $output .= '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
    $output .= '<p>'.$content.'</p>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I need to specify extact shortcode. I need to express this condition:

Comment: If shortcode number is empty display shortcode icon

Comment: just make it bit more clear now it's showing both values bellow:

  $output .= '<span><i class="fa fa-'.$icon.' icon-custom-style"></i></span>';
    $output .= '<span><p class="icon-custom-style">'.$number.'</p></span>'

I just need to display one of the output above.

Comment: strange the code above should work I guess but it doesn't. I mean the icon is displayed ok but when it should display number it's empty

[feature icon="" number="1" title="Něco přestane fungovat" color="1"]Objeví se chyba aplikace, něco nefunguje tak jak má.[/feature]

Comment: I just double check that I understand the means of empty same way as PHP language do e.g icon="" means empty